# AWS Elastic Beanstalk single instance with SSL config throws "HTTP method names must be tokens"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to use `HTTPs` in my Spring boot application so I added config files for `Elastic Beanstalk` (Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.1). Here is the config for HTTPS server:

```
server {
    listen       443 default ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:6080;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

The config seems to apply, but when I make a request using `HTTPs` the app throws this exception:

```
2018-06-17 09:40:55.245  INFO 29898 --- [nio-6080-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor:
Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:426) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar!/:8.5.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

I guess the problem is that the server listens for `HTTPs` requests but my app expects `HTTP` request but I am not really sure. What should I do?

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().csrf()
                .disable();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes this problem occur because of HTTPs Request hit from client side. So solution is to

**Configuring Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment's Load Balancer to Terminate HTTPS**

To update your AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to use HTTPS, you need to configure an HTTPS listener for the load balancer in your environment. Two types of load balancer support an HTTPS listener: Classic Load Balancer and Application Load Balancer.

You can use either the Elastic Beanstalk console or a configuration file to configure a secure listener and assign the certificate.

Note

Single-instance environments don't have a load balancer and don't support HTTPS termination at the load balancer.

**Configuring a Secure Listener Using the Elastic Beanstalk Console**

[image: s1]
[image: s2]

**Configuring a Secure Listener Using a Configuration File**

You can configure a secure listener on your load balancer with one of the following configuration files.

Example .ebextensions/securelistener-clb.config

Use this example when your environment has a Classic Load Balancer. The example uses options in the aws:elb:listener namespace to configure an HTTPS listener on port 443 with the specified certificate, and to forward the decrypted traffic to the instances in your environment on port 80.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:1234567890123:certificate/####################################
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    InstancePort: 80
```

Replace the highlighted text with the ARN of your certificate. The certificate can be one that you created or uploaded in AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) (preferred), or one that you uploaded to IAM with the AWS CLI.

For more information about Classic Load Balancer configuration options, see Classic Load Balancer Configuration Namespaces.

Example .ebextensions/securelistener-alb.config

Use this example when your environment has an Application Load Balancer. The example uses options in the aws:elbv2:listener namespace to configure an HTTPS listener on port 443 with the specified certificate. The listener routes traffic to the default process.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    Protocol: HTTPS
    SSLCertificateArns: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:1234567890123:certificate/####################################
```

**Configuring a Security Group**

If you configure your load balancer to forward traffic to an instance port other than port 80, you must add a rule to your security group that allows inbound traffic over the instance port from your load balancer. If you create your environment in a custom VPC, Elastic Beanstalk adds this rule for you.

You add this rule by adding a Resources key to a configuration file in the .ebextensions directory for your application.

The following example configuration file adds an ingress rule to the AWSEBSecurityGroup security group, which allows traffic on port 1000 from the load balancer's security group.

Example .ebextensions/sg-ingressfromlb.config

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"]}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 1000
      FromPort: 1000
      SourceSecurityGroupName: {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBLoadBalancer" , "SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName"]}
```

Hope this will help you. Or refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Comment: Well, the thing is I don't want to use Load balancer because of it's pricing if it's possible to configure my app and do it for free. I think maybe I will be forced to use Load balancer but I am trying to find a different solution.

Comment: Also I tried the Load Balancer once and I had a problem because the application wasn't responding to any requests. It was somehow unreachable.

Comment: For my issue with load balancer I created a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896930/aws-elastic-beanstalk-environment-with-classic-load-balancer-not-responding

Comment: @ankit what is your justification for speculating that `proxy_pass http://localhost:6080;` would *ever* send an HTTPS request upstream?  I don't see how that could be possible.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have no justification for that but `HTTP` requests will automatically be redirected to`HTTPS` from code i.e http://localhost:6080 will be automatically redirected to https://localhost:8443

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot And using `AWS` config we can change `instance protocol` to `listener protocol`.